# sys.executable returns None with custom python installation

Tags: python, scripting

I'm using Blender 2.92 (Windows 10) and it finds my Python installation in my Anaconda virtual environment as I have replaced its default python with that of my virtual environment using a hard link to the folder. I can import all of the modules of the virtual environment. I installed [blender_notebook](https://github.com/cheng-chi/blender_notebook) and followed its instructions; however, when I try to open a jupyter notebook it tells me Blender can't find the python binary. Opening up the blender scripting console, typing `print(sys.executable)` returns None. Doing the same in Anaconda Prompt with interactive python gives me the correct executable.

Why is the executable different even though the environment is the same? How do I set the python executable in blender?

Comment: Hello, whats does `bpy.app.binary_path_python` return ?

Comment: Consider asking on https://github.com/cheng-chi/blender_notebook/issues

Comment: @Gorgious It returns None along with the deprecation warning

Comment: @batFINGER I'll take a look, thanks

Comment: AFAIK `sys.exectutable` is either picked up via `argv[0]` (not the case in blender) or via the path environment variable, `os.environ['PATH']`  Getting `None` suggests this is not set with your setup.

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you for the information! I have the folder with python.exe in my path (verified by printing out os.environ['PATH'] in Blender) and it still returns None. Is there any way to force it to find the executable?